# How could an hard-token be packaged such that the recipient could trust it?

Tags: hardware, physical, tamper-resistance

I purchased a Yubikey NEO, which arrived in a small plastic thing, inside of a padded envelope. An attacker with access in transit would have had basically unlimited ability to manipulate it.

Which led me to thinking: assuming the recipient trusts the manufacturer, how could they package a hard-token such that the recipient could use it *without* needing to trust the postal system that transited it?

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are built to be tamper resistant so that you can't just open it up and mess with the circuitry and inner components.

The pin for the tokens are also delivered via another channel(Either the token or the pin is handed in person by the bank, RA or the institute that's responsible for the tokens) so that an attacker can't access both the pin and the hardware token.

Also the key used to generate OTPs "can be" based on the entered pin so with a wrong pin you'd get invalid passwords generated, so without having the right pin a guy getting access to the hardware token cannot do much(he will have access to a part of the key that's used to generate one time passwords).

Answer (score 1):

What kind of threat/attacker are you interested in protecting against?

If you only want to trust the manufacturer, you should pick it up directly from the manufacturer.

If you trust the tamper-resistance of the device, if the token utilizes a public/private key pair (the NEOs do), you can obtain the public key digitally directly from the manufacturer independently of the shipment, then compare it when it arrives.  An attacker could still attach something to the token to either monitor its use, remotely activate it, or potentially MitM it if you aren't always paying attention to what key pair is being used.

Tamper-evident packaging is a thing too, but would require you to be extremely familiar with the packaging so you know how to spot a counterfeit, and might not protect you still from a well-funded or state attacker.